# Using Groupby to create a unique identifier by group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Please see the dummy set below.

I'm not sure why it is not creating unique groups for each combination. I used to use an alteration of the code for a single grouping.

Beforehand the result I received was a group column that was as shown in the expected output column.

```
data={'Company':['A','B','A','B'],'zip':[223,223,224,224],'AOI':[10,10,20,20],'Expected Output':[1,1,2,2]}

df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.sort_values('zip')

df['Group'] = (df.groupby(['zip','AOI']).cumcount()==0).astype(int)
df['Group'] = df['Group'].cumsum()
```

My interpretation is we are counting the combinations of both unique zip's and unique AOI then summing them down.

Where am I going wrong?

Appreciate the assistance

Comment: Which version of Pandas are you running? When I execute this code I have the `Group` column exactly as the `Expected Output` describes it. (pandas 1.0.3)

Comment: Same in Pandas 1.0.1, `df['Group'] ` is `[1,1,2,2]`

Comment: I have version 1.0.3

Comment: The output I am getting is 1,2,3,4